# Pentaho install error: Error running initdb.exe -U postgres -E UTF8 -D

Tags: postgresql, pentaho

I am new to Pentaho, I just download a Pentaho Business Analytics 64 bit version(My os is Windows 64bit). When I install, I'm getting an "Error running initdb.exe -U postgres -E UTF8 -D C:/PENTAH~1/POSTGR~1/data" message. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?Thanks!

Comment: Is initdb.exe in your path ? Besides, as per http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-initdb.html, the -D shall specify a directory. Yours seems empty. Did you cut-and-paste the whole thing ?

Comment: try this link http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/3780.page . Might be of some help !!

Comment: Sorry, I have added the full content of the error message

Comment: @liminche if you try to edit this post make sure you edit it while being logged in to your account - edits as a guest will be rejected since there's no way to tell if it's really you or just some random guy trying to add false info to your question.

Comment: sorry, I will re-edit

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if Postgres is already installed in your system with port 5432, using `netstat -a`
2. This error most likely appears when there's problem while installing Postgres. Go to "My Computer" right-click "properties", choose "Advanced System Settings",  "Environmental Variables". In "system variables" for the variable `ComSpec` remove the semicolon after `cmd.exe`. This worked for me and allowed me to install Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I have used existing PostgreSQL instead of bundled that solved my problem.